# Understanding Risk-based authentication (Google case)

Tags: authentication, gmail

I am trying to access my Gmail account. I have the correct password. When I click on login it asks for a confirmation code sent to my recovery email. Hopefully, the recovery email does not have this strange procedure and I could log in to my recovery email and entered the confirmation code sent to my recovery email. When again it asked me to enter a phone number and enter the verification code sent to it. I entered my phone number and verification code, and at the end, it says "Google couldn’t verify this account belongs to you."

So I have my password, I have access to my recovery email and I also gave my phone number to them (which I don't understand how giving my phone number is related to security) and I still can not log in!

So what should I do to access my account?

Comment: Thats a question for the Google accounts team, not a security forum :)